# How does Notepad++ save the state of the workspace?

Tags: notepad++, state, implementation

I see that once I open a new file and write something in it, even if I don't save it, that file will also open when I open notepad++ again. So how is saving the state of the workspace in notepad++ implemented, even if I don't save it? Can anyone point me to the source code for it's implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: It saves it in the folder `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly simple:
There's a session.xml file in the user-folder which saves which files were opened and contains a link to them. If a file was not saved yet, it is also stored in the user folder.
The user folder in Windows is here:

```
C:\Users\your user\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

There's the session.xml. Open it in any editor and you see the open files. The not saved files point to the backup folder with a filename like new 1@2015-10-05_114609
Hope that helped a little.

Comment: sorry, I'm new at this, but I also want to know how this xml file is created and read.

Comment: Um, that is not really a question which needs to be asked here. Ask google for reading and writing xml in your preferred programming language.

Comment: I don't think @user3248186 asked about editing XML files. He likely meant when and how that file is created, loaded, updated etc. Which is, indeed, unclear, as there's a separate "workspace" and a "session" concept in NP++ (you can even assign different file extensions to them), but the real difference is obscured. Even today, you can e.g. `Open` a workspace, but there's no clear way to `Save` it. Etc. (N.B.: the question apparently, and understandably, confuses the two.)